# Java - How to implement functions in a heap-based priority queue

Tags: java, heap, priority-queue

For a programming assignment, I have been working on creating a program that reads an input file and sorts the data inside using a self-made max heap priority queue. The data file has lines that either read "insert [a name] [a number]", or "remove". For this priority queue, we need to make a function for inserting and removing objects. Each object in the queue contains the name as a string, and the priority as a integer. I have to implement this heap based on an array with a size of 255.

My question is, I'm having difficulty implementing my insert and remove functions to work as specified. I'll provide 1) how they need to work, 2) pseudocode I've made, and 3) the actual Java code I've implemented. Both of my functions do not work exactly as I intend for them to, so I could use some direction from more experienced programmers.

1) insert(name, priority): this function should take a name of type string and a priority of type integer, and inserts them into the priority queue.
   remove(): this function should remove the object with the highest priority value and return the name string from the object.

2) As background, I have three classes for this program: First, the "main" class containing implementation for reading the file and using the functions. Second, the "name" class, which creates the name object containing the name string and priority int , a constructor, and a compareTo method for comparing the priority values of two objects. Third, the "priorityqueue" class, contains the insert and remove functions. Now, here is the pseudocode I made for those two functions:

insert:

- Check if the array is full (when num = 255), throw if true
- Create the object from the input file with a name string and priority int
- Insert the object at num
- Use a while loop to swap the two objects at insertion
- Update num (num++)

remove:

- Save the first object
- Move the last object to the first
- Update num (num--)
- Use a while loop to determine the larger child and return it.

3) Here is the code I have so far. I'll provide my name and priority queue classes, in case my name class is what's giving me trouble.

Priority Queue class:

```
public class PriorityQueue 
{
int num; //amount of things in array 
int idx; //index of current name object
Name[] names = new Name[255];

public void insert(String name, int priority)
{
    while (num != 255)
    {
        Name addName = new Name(name, priority);
        names[num] = addName;
        num++;

        while(idx != 0 || names[idx].CompareTo(names[(idx-1)/2]))
        {
            Name temp = names[idx];
            names[idx] = names[(idx-1)/2];
            names[(idx-1)/2] = temp;

            idx = (idx-1)/2;
        }
    }
}

public Name remove()
{
    Name temp2 = names[0];
    //Save first element

    names[0] = names[idx];
    //Move last element to first

    num--;
    while(idx < Math.max(2*idx+1,2*idx+2))
    {
        if(names[idx].CompareTo(names[(idx-1)/2]))
                {
                    Name temp3 = names[idx];
                    names[idx] = names[(idx-1)/2];
                    names[(idx-1)/2] = temp3;
                }
    }
    return temp2;
}
```

}

Name class:

```
public class Name implements Comparable
{
String name;
int priority;

public Name(String n, int i)
{
    name = n;
    priority = i;
}

public boolean CompareTo(Name obj)
{
    if(priority < obj.priority)
    {
        return false;
    }

    else if(priority > obj.priority)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Surely this is wrong: `while (num != 255) {`. And you said "throw if true", no trace of that in the code.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: You are correct that I forgot the throw. But why do you say the while condition is incorrect? One of the specifications for this assignment is our queue contain no more than 255 elements, so I want this loop to run until num is greater than 255, since it represents the number of elements in the queue.

Comment: Because it's in the method whose job is to insert one entry into the heap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems. First, in your `insert` method:

```
public void insert(String name, int priority)
{
    while (num != 255)
    {
        Name addName = new Name(name, priority);
        names[num] = addName;
        num++;

        while(idx != 0 || names[idx].CompareTo(names[(idx-1)/2]))
        {
            Name temp = names[idx];
            names[idx] = names[(idx-1)/2];
            names[(idx-1)/2] = temp;

            idx = (idx-1)/2;
        }
    }
}
```

The `while (num != 255)` shouldn't be there. You should check to see if `num == 255`, and throw an exception if it is.

Then, you need to initialize `idx`. That is:

```
        Name addName = new Name(name, priority);
        names[num] = addName;
        idx = num;
        num++;
```

And your `while` condition should use `&&` rather than `||`. Otherwise you'll do the swap every time `idx` is not equal to 0.

In your `remove` method:

```
public Name remove()
{
    Name temp2 = names[0];
    //Save first element

    names[0] = names[idx];
    //Move last element to first

    num--;
    while(idx < Math.max(2*idx+1,2*idx+2))
    {
        if(names[idx].CompareTo(names[(idx-1)/2]) > 0)
                {
                    Name temp3 = names[idx];
                    names[idx] = names[(idx-1)/2];
                    names[(idx-1)/2] = temp3;
                }
    }
    return temp2;
}
```

You don't want `names[idx]` there, because you don't know what `idx` is. You want:

```
names[0] = names[num-1]; // get last item in the heap
```

Your `while` condition here is goofy. `Math.max(2*idx+1,2*idx+2)` will always return `2*idx+2`, unless `idx` is negative. And, again, you haven't even initialized `idx`. What you want here is:

```
idx = 0;
while (idx < num)
```

Now, what you're trying to do is see if `names[idx]` is smaller than either of its children. And, if so, select the largest of the two children to swap it with. So:

```
while (idx < num)
{
    int largestChild = idx*2+1;
    if (largestChild >= num) break; // idx is at a leaf level
    if (largestChild+1 < num)
    {
        // compare the two children
        if (names[largestChild].compareTo(names[largestChild+1]) < 0)
        {
            largestChild = largestChild+1;
        }
    }
    if (names[idx] < names[largestChild])
    {
        // swap, moving the item down
        temp = names[idx];
        names[idx] = names[largestChild];
        names[largestChild] = temp;
        idx = largestChild;
    }
    else
    {
        // item is in the proper place
        break;
    }
}
```

I would suggest making `idx` a method-scoped variable in both methods. There's no need for it to be a global, and making it local to the methods forces you to initialize it before you use it, rather than potentially (as in your existing code) using a stale value.

I think you need to change your `Name` class's `CompareTo` function. The [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) `compareTo` function must return:

> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

So you should have:

```
public boolean CompareTo(Name obj)
{
    if(priority < obj.priority)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if (priority > obj.priority)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, @Jim Mischel! I have one more question for you involving my PriorityQueue class. I assume I need at least one constructor in order to print the heap in my main class. If so, what input arguments should the constructor take? Would it be the Name object, or the string name and int priority (which obviously the Name object contains, but I've attempted both ways and keep getting a null pointer error)?

Comment: @vertoslash: By the way, I think your implementation of `Comparable` is wrong. Shouldn't it be `int compareTo(Name obj)` as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)?

Comment: @vertoslash: I don't see a constructor anywhere. Are you asking about your `PriorityQueue` constructor? I'd think something like `PriorityQueue myQueue = new PriorityQueue();` would be sufficient. Then, do all operations on the `myQueue` reference.

Comment: One question about your while loop for the remove function. In netbeans, I get an error on the if statement:

    if(names[largestChild] < names[largestChild+1])
            {
                largestChild = largestChild+1;
            }

Netbeans says I can't compare these with a < operand, since the arrays both contain Name objects instead of integers. So how should I do the comparison here?

Comment: @vertoslash: Probably something like `if (names[largestChild].CompareTo(names[largestChild+1]) < 0)`. You'll also need to change the comparison in the insert. See my note about changing your `compareTo` method.

Comment: Thanks, I did make the change to my CompareTo, using int makes much more sense. Also, since I'm returning the string name, how should the return statement for remove work? Should I just return temp2 at the end, or return something in each loop? Basically I'm unsure of how to return the string name in my name class after each remove.

Comment: @vertoslash: I've updated my answer to reflect the `compareTo` change. On the return, it looks like returning `temp2` does what you want. Certainly you don't want to return anything each time through the loop.

Comment: Alright, so in my main class then I want to print the string name in the Name object when I use the pq.remove() function. How can I do this? Do I need to create a new toString method in Priority Queue that just prints the string name when I call it, or is there a better way? (Sorry about all of this, I almost have it figured out!)

Comment: @vertoslash: Seems like you could just output the `Name` property from that class. Assuming it's accessible. Or you could create a `toString()` method. We've gone rather far afield from the priority queue, though. If you have additional trouble, you should probably ask a new question.

Comment: Well, I actually have one last question about the Priority Queue. For my insert and remove functions, now that we changed the .CompareTo to return an integer, I'm getting some funky outputs from the loops that use .CompareTo. Just to make sure I have things correct, in .insert, the while loop should use while(idx != 0 && names[idx].CompareTo(names[(idx-1)/2] == 1)) since we only want this swap to occur when parent has a lower priority than the child, right? And in .remove, if (names[idx] < names[largestChild]) should be if (names[idx].CompareTo(names[largestChild]) < 0)?

Comment: @vertoslash: You are correct. But use `> 0` rather than `== 1`. Don't assume that `compareTo` will return -1, 0, or 1. Assume < 0, 0, or > 0.

Comment: @vertoslash: By the way, if this answer helped you out or answered your question, it's customary to upvote and/or mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @ Jim Mischel, thank you so much for your assistance! I've marked your answer and upvoted, though my reputation hides the vote. Your answers were informative in understanding how to properly implement this structure!